# How to set preferences on Android

Tags: android, preferences

My app is clicked and does an action, without opening up a screen.

I use shared preferences to store my preferences.

I was wondering how to set up on the phone settings a bar that gets linked to the settings of my application after the user has done their one-time setup when starting the app for the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at [Preference Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html)

Comment: The problem with that I think is that I do not have a screen showing up for them to press preferences. I just have my app showing a preference screen on first start up, and then calling a background process on next startup. I need to add preferences to the actual android menu

Comment: then register a onClickListener and store the Prefences yourself

Comment: register an onClick listener for what exactly?

Comment: It is not possible to hook into the normal Options of the phone for a non Root App. You can however determine if the user has entered his settings once with an sharedPrefsBoolean and show him a UI Screen once if not

Comment: yes but then how would the user choose to get back to that setup screen, any ideas?

Comment: Then, what about building two apps, or at least, two starting Intents? In one You can define SharedPrefs as World-readable and read them in your second App or Intent.